# Object reference at application initialize after changing to solr search provider

Tags: solr, content-search

i encounter this error after changing my search provider from lucene to solr.

Some details:

- Sitecore 8.1 Update 1
- Solr 5.2.1
- Followed sitecore KB article          https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr
- IOC container choosen : Castle Windsor
- Followed this article to resolve this issue but still i couldnt get
  out of this issue https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

  ```
  Server Error in '/' Application.
  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

  Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Source Error: 

  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

  Stack Trace: 


  [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
     SolrNet.Schema.SolrSchemaParser.Parse(XDocument solrSchemaXml) +550
     Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() +994
     Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.Initialize() +169
     (Object , Object[] ) +111
     Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
     Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +227
     Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
     System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
     System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
     System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your version of Solr. Changes in the default `schema.xml` file that ship with 4.8+ can cause this issue.

To Resolve this use the following steps:

1. Make the following changes in the default schema.xml file distributed with Solr:

   - enclose all  and  elements in the  tag.
   - enclose all  elements in the  tag.
2. Pass the modified schema.xml file to the Build Solr Schema Wizard to add the Sitecore-specific configuration.
3. Put the resulting file to the configuration folder of the Solr core.
4. Find the following dynamic field definition in the schema.xml file:

   `<dynamicField name="*_pi" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" />`

   change the mapping type from "pint" to "tint"

   `<dynamicField name="*_pi" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />`
5. Reload the core to apply schema changes.
6. Restart the application pool of the website to initialize Sitecore indexes using the updated schema.xml file.

This is documented by Sitecore on the [Solr Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897) kb article. Please read through that to make sure there are no other compatibility issues with your version of Solr.

Comment: I have done this before & still receiving this error:( i will update the question accordingly.

Comment: People, if you down vote something - add a reason why, maybe the answer can be improved.

Comment: Solr is hosted as a windows service & after every change in schema.xml, i'm suppose to restart this service. I was missing this :(